NetBSD "-f" option in find
I can't understand what "-f" option to find command on NetBSD mean.
Manual: https://man.netbsd.org/find.1 says

-f      Specifies a file hierarchy for find to traverse.  File hierarchies may also be specified as the operands immediately following the options.

Usage:

find [-H | -L | -P] [-dEhsXx] -f file [file ...] [expression]


find [-H | -L | -P] [-dEhsXx] file [file ...] [expression]

I would expect the two following calls to be equivalent:
home# find ./ -name "*c"
./1.c

home# find -f ./ -name "*c"
find: unknown option -- n
find: unknown option -- a
find: unknown option -- m
find: unknown option -- e
./
./1.c
find: *c: No such file or directory

Instead to make second equivalent I have to run
home# find -f ./ -- -name "*c"
./1.c

Am I missing something?

Have you tried find --name '*.c' -f ./ ?

@SottoVoce, here is result: home# find --name '*.c' -f ./ find: unknown option -- - find: unknown option -- n find: unknown option -- a find: unknown option -- m find: unknown option -- e find: -f: unknown option

-f is not required: "File hierarchies may also be specified as the operands immediately following the options" . However the man document (the Bugs section) explains when one may need to use -f ... --: "As there is no delimiter separating options and file names or file names and the expression, it is difficult to specify files named -xdev or !.  These problems are handled by the -f option and the getopt(3) -- construct."

@SekstusEmpiryk Sorry, I put too many - characters in the -name option.  Looks like user202311 has explained what the -f option is for (files named the same as command-line options)

BSD find parses the flags ([-H | -L | -P] [-dEhsXx] [-f file]) with getopt(), and uses the first non-option argument to separate the flags from the paths/expression.  Because it wants to support things like
$ find -f A -f B

it keeps trying to parse flags even after it sees -f file.  But that means if you feed it -f A -name ..., it will try to parse -name as a flag and fail.  As you found out, -- will force the end of the flags, but so will anything that doesn't start with -, for example:
$ find -f ./ \( -name '*c' \)

This is hinted at by the manpage:

 As there is no delimiter separating options and file names or file names
 and the expression, it is difficult to specify files named ``-xdev'' or
 ``!''.  These problems are handled by the -f option and the getopt(3)
 ``--'' construct.


Side note: this is the source of my favourite incompatibility between BSD and GNU find:
$ find -follow \( -name foo \)
find: ollow: No such file or directory
$ gfind -follow \( -name foo \)
./foo


And the GNU equivalent of BSD's find -f "$file1" -f "$file2" -- ... to be able to run it on arbitrary file paths is find -files0-from <(printf '%s\0' "$file1" "$file") ... for which you need version 4.9 or newer and a shell with process substitution support.

Right, or printf '%s\0' "$file1" "$file2" | find -files0-from - ... (if the rest of the find command doesn't need stdin)
